# Copy URL and paste on button, and add a default parameter if there's nothing after "/"

Tags: javascript, html

The script below *is working* but if there's no parameter after the "/" it **doesn't work**.

**Is it possible to add a "default" parameter if that's nothing after the "/"?**

> **Default parameter**: "*XV-MEL-OM-REVHL-X-X-POP-X-X*"
>
> Example: www.domain.com/test-new/**defaultparameter**

My URL is:  http://lp.inversapub.com/test-new/

```js
function Copy() 
{
    var Url = document.getElementById("paste-box");
    Url.value = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    Url.focus();
    Url.select();  
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<form action="https://ws.inversapub.com/subscribe" method="POST" target="hiddenFrame">
    
    <input name="emailAddress" type="email" required="" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Preencha um endereço de e-mail válido.')" placeholder="Coloque seu e-mail aqui" class="input-email-popup">
    
    <input type="submit" value="QUERO DOBRAR MEU DINHEIRO AINDA ESTE ANO" onclick="Copy();" class="btn-submit-popup om-trigger-conversion">
    <input type="hidden" name="sourceId" id="paste-box" value="XV-MEL-OM-REVHL-X-X-POP-X-X">
    
    <input name="listCode" type="hidden" value="inv_hotlist_revhl"/>
    
    <input name="redirect" type="hidden"  value="#" />
    
    <input name="email_page" type="hidden" value="inv_welcome_revhl"/>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try updating the copy function to use default value if nothing is provided after '/'.

```
function Copy() 
{
    var Url = document.getElementById("paste-box");
  let parameter = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if(parameter) {
      Url.value = parameter
    } else {
      Url.value = "XV-MEL-OM-REVHL-X-X-POP-X-X";
    }
    Url.focus();
    Url.select();  
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```